# How to SetActive() Prefabbed Canvas child button/text in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have prefabbed my canvas which contains children(up button, attack button, etc.). I have also prefabbed my player and now am passing the prefabbed canvas to the player in the editor using a SerializedField.

Here is the canvas prefab object structure:

[image]

Here is the Player.cs structure(passing the canvas prefab in the player prefab):

[image]

Here is the code for fetching the children of the canvas attached to the player so that I can SetActive(true/false) to the buttons.:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Canvas canvas;
    GameObject upButton;
    GameObject downButton;
    GameObject leftButton;
    GameObject rightButton;
    GameObject jumpButton;
    GameObject rollButton;
    GameObject attackButton;
    [SerializeField] float runningSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpVelocity = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float rollSpeed = 3f;

 void Start()
    {                 
        AssignUIToGameObjects();
        rigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        upButton.SetActive(false); // -----------------------------> Not working
        downButton.gameObject.SetActive(false); // -----------------------------> Not working          
    }

    public void AssignUIToGameObjects()
    {                      

        leftButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;        
        rightButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
        upButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(3).gameObject;
        downButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(4).gameObject;
        jumpButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject;
        rollButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(11).gameObject;
        attackButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(12).gameObject;
    }
}
```

Prior to prefabbing, the `GameObject upButton` was actually `[SerializedField] Button upButton`. But since, you cannot pass children of a prefab to another prefab in unity editor, I had to pass the entire canvas prefab to the player.

But I can't seem to do so, the `upButton.SetActive(false)` is not disabling the up and down keys.

What is going wrong, is it a syntax problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would add a script to the canvas parent that takes care of the references. Your player would have a reference to that script so you can communicate via methods. That would also minimise the code in Player not being about player actions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will look into this. But why would people dislike the question? Just curious tho, am I breaking a protocol or rule or was my question lacking information? To avoid future dislikes lol.

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now